# Alternative Android media players

Tags: java, android

here's my code for a very basic android sound player, on button press I expect a sound to play, or an IOException to be caught - seems simple enough. Instead I get "QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present", so how am I meant to play my track if there's no player available - & what should I do as an alternative?
I understand it's already been raised, but no trivial solution was given.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button motivate = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.motivate);
        motivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   // On click randomly select a sound then play it
                try {
                    play();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
        }
    }

    public void play() throws IOException {
        stop();

        int[] sound = {R.raw.a, R.raw.b, R.raw.c, R.raw.d, R.raw.e, R.raw.f, R.raw.g, R.raw.h, R.raw.i, R.raw.j, R.raw.k, R.raw.l, R.raw.m, R.raw.n, R.raw.o};

        player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, sound[0]);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
                stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace. Also note that to play music, you need to call `play()` on the `MediaPlayer`, which your code does not appear to be doing.

Comment: `@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   // On click randomly select a sound then play it
                try {
                    play();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }` Well it definitely calls play.

Comment: No, that calls `play()` on `MainActivity`. Nothing in your code listing calls `play()` on the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: It's an onClick listener, it waits for a button with the ID motivate to be click, and when it is, it runs the code. There also is no instantiation for play() in MediaPlayer it's MediaPlayer player = *some media player* then player.start(); runs it's configuration. You're attempting to address a question that doesn't exist. My problem, is not the one you're thinking of.

Comment: "then player.start(); runs it's configuration" -- you are not calling `start()` either, at least in the code that you show in your question. "You're attempting to address a question that doesn't exist" -- I was attempting to reconcile your reported crash with the fact that the crash cannot seem to happen with the code from your question. This is also why I suggested that you post your stack trace. You have not done so. If you want someone else to help, please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example, as is covered in this site's documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample
We used it for stream playback

Comment: That's useful cheers, but I'm sure you can play music or sounds from mp3, m4a files etc without having to download an entirely new player.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the answer to this was actually rather simple. MediaPlayer is an import that only 8/10 will work depending on your flavour of android and kernel. A constant is SoundPool; this will load and play a sound as required.

Comment: SoundPool only works for short sound clips, otherwise it runs out of heap space.